# fire matlab uitable cellselection callback on mouse up

Tags: matlab, callback, mouse, matlab-uitable

I have a uitable with a checkbox column.
I want to toggle the checkbox status for each selected cell. Clearly, that does not work when the callback function executes when the user is still adding cells to the selection.
It should rather execute not earlier than the user releases the mouse.

The normal behaviour of a cell selection callback function however fires every time the selection area canges.

How can one change this behaviour?

A